# Replaced Screen "Searching..." - cannot find network provider

Tags: iphone, screen

EDIT 16/06/2015 - Replaced Cellular Antenna - no fix.

I own a small IT repair business and we've recently expanded into the iPhone/iPad repair sector. A customer came in with an iPhone 4s, and the customer had replaced the screen for themselves. The issue is that the iPhone now can't be used for phone calls, texts or internet access. Instead of stating their provider in the top left of the screen it simply says "Searching...".

I have confirmed that it is *not* a SIM based error.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chances are they ripped or damaged the antenna(s) for cellular service/WiFi.

Comment: I see, and that's replaceable?

Comment: It most certainly is! Follow this [link](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/iPhone+4S+Cellular+Antenna+Replacement/7276) for an iFixit guide

Comment: @TGYK That is one of the biggest risks with repairing things on your own at home instead of letting someone else which knows how do it.

Comment: Ah great, I'll give that a go and keep you posted!